# VBScript recursive function issue returning value

Tags: vbscript

I am fighting what should be simple VBScript function here.  The goal of my script is to take 2 input values and find the matching subfolder. I then want the function to return the path to that folder. Below is what I have, but am having trouble making it return the value. It doesn't seem to be exiting the function and returning the value.

Here is what I have so far.

```
Function GetFolderName(folderspec,Computer)
    WScript.Echo "checking: " & folderspec
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder(folderspec)
    If UCase(objFolder.Name) = UCase(Computer) Then
        GetFolderName = folderspec
        Exit Function
    End If
    Set arrSubfolders = objFolder.SubFolders
    For Each f1 in arrSubfolders
            folderspec = GetFolderName(f1.Path,Computer)
    Next
End Function

strFolder = GetFolderName("C:\Test","Trial3")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
....
For Each f1 in objFolder.SubFolders
    GetFolderName = GetFolderName(f1.Path,Computer)
    If GetFolderName <> vbEmpty Then Exit For
Next
....
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  I was so close!

Answer (score 1):

Like **MC ND** you can try like this :

```
Function GetFolderName(folderspec,Computer)
'WScript.Echo "checking: " & folderspec
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder(folderspec)
    If UCase(objFolder.Name) = UCase(Computer) Then
        GetFolderName = folderspec
        Exit Function
    End If
    Set arrSubfolders = objFolder.SubFolders
    For Each f1 in objFolder.SubFolders
        GetFolderName = GetFolderName(f1.Path,Computer)
        If GetFolderName <> vbEmpty Then Exit For
    Next
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
MsgBox GetFolderName("C:\Test","Trial3")
```

Comment: Thanks for making it an easy copy/paste!